# View all comments in GitHub

Tags: github

When searching for some text in a GitHub issue with lots of comments, I first need to have all the comments loaded.

Currently I search for the text `items not shown`, and then click the `View more` link.

[image: tet]

I sometimes need to do this multiple times.

Is there a way to load all comments in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also annoyed me, I wrote the following userscript to solve it (as of Dec 2021).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Show all comments on github issue
// @namespace    https://www.taylrr.co.uk
// @version      0.1
// @description  Automatically clicks the "xxx hidden items" button on Github issue pages to successively load in all the comments in the page on load.
// @author       taylor8294
// @match        https://github.com/*/issues/*
// @icon         https://icons.duckduckgo.com/ip2/github.com.ico
// @grant        none
// @license      GPLv3
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    function ready(fn) {
        if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
            fn();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
        }
    }

    function clickButton(){
        let button = document.querySelector('.ajax-pagination-form button');
        if(button){
            if(!button.disabled) button.click();
            setTimeout(clickButton,50);
        } else console.log('All comments are now showing.')
    }
    ready(()=>{setTimeout(clickButton,2000)});
})();
```

Install it in your userscript manager of choice (*eg* [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/), [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/), [Userscripts Safari](https://github.com/quoid/userscripts) etc) and once the page is loaded it will just keep clicking the button for you until all the comments are showing. I've also published the script on [Greasyfork (#437823)](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/437823-show-all-comments-on-github-issue) if you prefer to install from there.

Comment: How does this handle the multiple times case?